# CSS code to expand a photo slider plugin to span the web page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins

Need CSS code for a child theme's style.css to expand an image slider plugin to span the entire web page.  See photography.koshoart.com

(I am trying to get something like brettwestonarchive.com and am also using the Royal Slider and the Skeleton Theme)

Here's my CSS code so far:

```
/* make "parent" containers 100% width and height */

html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

/* stretch slider to 100% width and height */

‪#‎new‬-royalslider-1 {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
height: auto !important;
width: auto !important;
}
```

Right now the code just moves the slider to the top of the web page.

Here's the suggestion I got from tech support: "You need to apply 100% height to all parent containers, not just HTML and BODY."

I believe more selectors need to be added to the first rule (correct?), and I suppose I would find them in the source for the main page where the slider is located. But how do I know which selectors to add?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: check your `#new-royalslider-1` parent container , that should have the 100% height and a `position:relative`

Comment: Tried this and the image filled the container with wrong aspect ration and the container is still not full width.

Comment: You cannot have it full width .. coz your `#content` has a fixed width and that's your parent container

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#new-royalslider-1 img {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Tried it and now the entire image slider does appear but not full page width (with the arrows off-center) - see photography.koshoart.com